# Change the output of groupy and apply() functions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby, panel-data

I have a panel data series and I would like to apply a function over all the unique rows in the column mgrno. I have decided to use the groupby and apply function but the results are in a weird format that I can't use, I would like to be able to convert the results into a dataframe where I can transpose and define my own column names for each unique mgrno.
I will put the sample source data for example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

## Load raw data

import os, requests, zipfile, io
if not os.path.exists('DataEstimation.xlsx'):
    r = requests.get('https://github.com/ralphkoijen/demand_asset_pricing/blob/master/Data.zip?raw=true') 
    z = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(r.content))
    z.extractall()
```

I define my function:

```
def regress(mdata):
     mdata = np.array(mdata)
     mgrno = mdata[:,0:1]
     vrweight = mdata[:,2:3]
     vloc       = np.argwhere(vrweight>0)[:,0]
     mdata0     = mdata[vloc]
     mchars     = mdata0[:,3:8]
     vLNme      = mdata0[:,8:9]
     vLNmeIV    = mdata0[:,9:10]
     vLNrweight = np.log(vrweight[vloc])

     dT         = len(vLNme)
     vones      = np.ones((dT,1))

     mX         = np.concatenate([vLNme,mchars,vones],axis=1)
     mZ         = np.concatenate([vLNmeIV,mchars,vones],axis=1)
     vb_linearIV = np.linalg.inv(mZ.T@mX)@mZ.T@vLNrweight
     if vb_linearIV[0] > .99:
    
       mX = np.concatenate([mchars,vones],axis=1)
       vb_linearIV = np.linalg.inv(mX.T@mX)@mX.T@(vLNrweight - .99*vLNme)
       vb_linearIV = np.concatenate([np.array([[.99]]), vb_linearIV],axis=0)
     return(np.round(vb_linearIV,4))
```

I need to change my input into a dataframe to use groupby and apply:

```
mdata = pd.read_excel('DataEstimation.xlsx')
 result = mdata.groupby('mgrno').apply(regress)
```

Unfortunately the result is in this object format that for whatever reason I can not convert and manipulate

```
print(result)
mgrno
23000    [[0.46], [1.4798], [-1.0247], [-3.1612], [0.36...
90457    [[0.99], [0.0891], [0.2689], [0.8588], [0.1854...
dtype: object
```

This is I would like my results to look like:

```
d = {'mgrno': [23000, 90457], 'var_1': [0.46, 0.99],
     'var_2': [1.4798, 0.0891], 'var_3': [-1.0247, 0.2689],
     'var_4': [-3.1612, 0.8588],'var_5': [0.36, 0.1854],'var_6': [0.2935, 0.2162],'var_3': [-12.5886, 0.2689]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

print(df)
   mgrno  var_1   var_2    var_3   var_4   var_5   var_6
0  23000   0.46  1.4798 -12.5886 -3.1612  0.3600  0.2935
1  90457   0.99  0.0891   0.2689  0.8588  0.1854  0.2162
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it.

My frame has 'raw' as the column name for list objects -

```
   mgrno                                                raw
0  23000  [[0.46], [1.4798], [-12.5886], [-3.1612], [0.3...
1  90457  [[0.99], [0.0891], [0.2689], [0.8588], [0.1854...
```

A function to transform the list of lists objects (the 'raw' column) and then return a single Series that will become a row in the returned DataFrame:

```
def pp(x):
    s1 = pd.Series(x['mgrno'], index=['mgrno'])
    s2 = pd.Series([v[0] for v in x['raw']])
    s2.rename(lambda x: 'var_' + str(x+1), inplace=True)
    return pd.concat([s1,s2])
```

Apply it:

```
df2 = df.apply(pp, axis=1)
df2

     mgrno  var_1   var_2    var_3   var_4   var_5   var_6
0  23000.0   0.46  1.4798 -12.5886 -3.1612  0.3600  0.2935
1  90457.0   0.99  0.0891   0.2689  0.8588  0.1854  0.2162
```